# jcarousel images don't scroll correct on chrome

Tags: jcarousel

$j("#carousel2_2").jcarousel({
        vertical: false,
        start: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 1,
        animation: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing',
        auto: parseInt(1),
        wrap: 'circular',
        itemFallbackDimension: 430

```
});
```

the problem is in chrome, it doesn't scroll correctly. It doesn't scrool to the whole width of the first image and go to second, instead scrolls partially to second and then second and third and so on.

Why?